# How to infer information from a cumulative frequency graph, and what it means practically

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

So I'm given a table of data, regarding

"An estimator working for a large construction company, is preparing a tender and trying to establish a rate for reinforcing bars in a concrete floor. Data from the work done over the past 5 years by the company is set out in the table below"

And I'm asked, how the estimator can make use of this data?

I've worked out the median to be 240, upper quartile to be 405, lower quartile to be 290, and hence interquartile range to be 115.

The x axis is output (kg/hour) of this concrete (I think) and y is obviously cumulative frequency.

But I'm not sure exactly how someone could "make use" of this information, and how I can relate it to the question.

Any help is great, thanks

Edit I don't think you need the table, but its a table of output (kg/hour) and frequency, which yields a typical ogive

Comment: Well, a cumulative frequency will tell you a likely upper bound on the production, as well as a lower bound. Either could be useful for planning.

Comment: What do you mean buy an upper or lower bound on the production?

Comment: For example the 5th and 95th percentile of kg/hr

Comment: Sorry, I'm really not getting what you're saying. The 5th and 95th percentile of kg/hr, how can he use those to prepare a tender, or Mae use o them otherwise? Is it something to do with production?

Comment: Why don't you explain what a tender is and provide the table in your post?

Comment: I didn't really know what a tender was until I looked up after seeing this question, and I have no clue about how I could put a table of the data up on here. But I guess the tender isn't the main thing, but rather how he can fix a rate for reinforcing bars in a concrete floor. I think a tender is just a formal form of auctioning your company and inviting bids for it. That's googles definition anyway